# FIltering CSV data using C++

Tags: c++, csv, filter

Sorry for asking a question that many may think has already been asked.

I have a very long CSV data file (dat.csv) with 5 columns. I have another short CSV (filter.csv) file with 1 column.

Now, I only need to extract columns from dat.csv where column-1 matches with that of column-1 of filter.csv.

I would usually do this in BASH using `sed/awk`. However, for some other reasons I need to do this within a C++ file. Can you suggest an efficient way to do this?

Sample Data:

data.csv

> ```
> ID,Name,CountryCode,District,Population
>
> 3793,NewYork,USA,NewYork,8008278
> 3794,LosAngeles,USA,California,3694820
> 3795,Chicago,USA,Illinois,2896016
> 3796,Houston,USA,Texas,1953631
> 3797,Philadelphia,USA,Pennsylvania,1517550
> 3798,Phoenix,USA ,Arizona,1321045
> 3799,SanDiego,USA,California,1223400
> 3800,Dallas,USA,Texas,1188580
> 3801,SanAntonio,USA,Texas,1144646
> ```

filter.csv

> ```
> 3793
> 3797
> 3798
> ```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1120140/10077  How does your question differ from this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some tips:

1. The stream from which you're reading the data needs to ignore the commas, so what it should to is set comma characters to whitespace using the `std::ctype<char>` facet imbued in its locale. Here's an example of modifying the classification table:

   ```
   struct ctype : std::ctype<char>
   {
   private:
       static mask* get_table()
       {
           static std::vector<mask> v(classic_table(),
                                      classic_table() + table_size);

           v[','] &= ~space;
           return &v[0];
       }
   public:
       ctype() : std::ctype<char>(get_table()) { }
   };
   ```
2. Read the first csv. file line-wise (meaning `std::getline()`). Extract the first word and compare it with an extraction from the second .csv file. Continue this until you reach the end of the first file:

   ```
   int main()
   {
       std::ifstream in1("test1.csv");
       std::ifstream in2("test2.csv");

       typedef std::istream_iterator<std::string> It;

       in1 >> comma_whitespace;
       in2 >> comma_whitespace;

       std::vector<std::string> in2_content(It(in2), It());
       std::vector<std::string> matches;

       while (std::getline(in1, line))
       {
           std::istringstream iss(line);
           It beg(iss);

           if (std::find(in2_content.begin(),
                         in2_content.end(), *beg) != in2_content.end())
           {
               matches.push_back(line);
           }
       }
   }

   // After the above, the vector matches should hold all the rows that
   // have the same ID number as in the second csv file
   ```

   `comma_whitespace` is a manipulator which changes the locale to the custom `ctype` defined above.

   <sub>Disclaimer: I haven't tested this code.</sub>

Comment: Thanks 0x499602D2 for taking the time to answer. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

This .csv sorting library might help:

http://www.partow.net/programming/dsvfilter/index.html

You could merge the columns of both tables into one larger table, and then query for matches in the new table (where column 1 of table A is and column 1 of table B is). Or maybe that library has functions for comparing tables.

Comment: I have just downloaded the library. However, I can not compile it. It seems that the parser of the Expression Toolkit library does not contain two functions cache_symbols and expression_symbols. Do you have the same problem ?

Comment: Sorry I missed your reply long ago :p and I'll look into whether and how I ended up using that library, and get back to you. (Have you found another working solution?)